# How to describe a mythological creature that English has no vocabulary for?

Tags: translation, language

The term is [妖精](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A6%96%E7%B2%BE), which can be translated into English as "fairy", "elf", "goblin". As noted, the Japanese literature uses 妖精 to describe the European fairy. The English translation of 白骨精 in 西游记 (Journey to the West) is "white bone demon". So, this word can be translated into English as fairy, elf, goblin, or demon.

Let's say an author is writing a fantasy story in Chinese first, using terms that are understood in a Chinese society. Then, the same author translates his/her own story into English and faces a problem. Which term should 妖精 be translated into (fairy, elf, goblin, or demon)? Or are the differences between the terms negligible, so the author can just pick a random one and go with it?

Comment: How would you translate a name? Would you attempt to Anglicize it or would you do it phonetically? Would you translate the meaning of someone's name or write the name itself?

Comment: I can't comment on the Chinese aspects, but fairies, elves, goblins and demons are very distinct in English, so you do need to choose the right one for your situation.

Comment: Both "elf" and "fairy" are highly problematic and ill-defined terms, not to mention goblin and demon. I think it would be a mistake to think "the European fairy" exists as a single well-defined thing. Traditional child-stealing fairies of northern European folklore are far more sinister than the flower fairies of modern children's books for example, and the fairies/elves of different regions also differ from each other. And then there are Tolkien's elves, D&D elves, and Warhammer elves to name but a few...

Comment: @Bob Not to mention the _types_ of elves -- dark, light, Harlequin, sun, moon, summer, winter, etc. (though those last two pairs are often just reskins of the first, sometimes with some form of 'grey' in the middle). That light/dark dichotomy especially applies to a _lot_ of different types of creatures, explicitly or implicitly; you might have "light humans" who care about each other and try to make sure everyone succeeds, and Pratchett-style wizards who... don't do that at all.

Comment: I don't think one should necessarily dismiss the possibility of a more-or-less literal translation. If the creature is malevolent, "white bone demon" might work pretty well. In fact, I wonder if this is where D&D got its "bone devil" or osyluth, which is often shown as stark white.

Comment: The sorts of things mentioned in the above comments really belong in an answer instead. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question or asking for clarification, not for partial answers; comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do.

Comment: Another idea could be to choose one of the words but have a picture on the cover of the book with the creature if that does not spoil anything.

Answer (score 45):

In your example, 白骨精, I'd say the 精 is not so much 'fairy' as it is in 妖精, but rather 'spirit' (like in 精霊), similar to how in English we can use the word 'spirit' to describe a lot of different types of ghouls and ghosts, so spirit might be a good choice as a kind of 'all round' title.

Anyway, I don't have a definite answer, but I would say there's two options.

Option one, rather than translating the other language into an English equivalent you could simply use the foreign word. For example, a 僵尸 would simply be 'jiangshi', rather than 'Chinese hopping vampire'. This would work best if what you're writing is set in a world or country that comes across as foreign to English readers anyway, whether you use English to describe the creatures or not. After all, most people are unfamiliar with foreign mythical creatures, so in some cases the English may give no more of an idea of what the creature is like than the original foreign word.

But then for option two (which is the one I'd use), to be honest I would just say to choose which word (ghoul, fairy, spirit, demon) fits with the image of the creature. Is it small and cute and not very mean? Fairy or spirit should do. Is it ugly and bad, but maybe not so deadly to humans? Maybe ghoul would work. Evil and malevolent and otherwise hurts people? Demon or devil it is.

When it comes to writing the author has a lot of leeway with naming and making up creatures, so I would go with whatever you feel fits the best, whether that be the English or the original word.

Comment: Great answer. I'd suggest this as a guiding principle: If you want the creature to feel _familiar_ to readers, use a familiar English word, even if that means adjusting reader expectations of how those creatures "work" in this piece. If you _don't_ want this to feel like one of the fantasy creatures readers already know, then use a new name -- a transliteration of the Chinese, or possibly making up a new name of your own.

Comment: I know the answer prefers the second option, but I honestly prefer the first one. Off the top of my head, I know English-language original works from Mercedes Lackey (Kitsune in Chrome Circle) and Jay Kristoff (Oni in his Lotus War series) did exactly this.

Comment: Why limit yourself to one? I think your answer is fantastic, but a very common technique is to explain both to the reader. For example (straight from wiki): A jiangshi, also known as a Chinese "hopping" vampire, is a type of reanimated corpse in Chinese legends and folklore. ----> Then simply use the terms interchangeably. The reader should recognize the terms are one in the same.

Comment: "For example, a 僵尸 would simply be 'jiangshi', rather than 'Chinese hoping vampire'." - Huh, assuming the jiangshi I've seen in anime are accurate, that's not something I'd call a vampire.  Zombie maybe.  Good example of a straight translation being more confusing for readers.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah, I agree the first option can work perfecty well, I just in general prefer to use the second (I have no issues with reading works with the first though!). I think it can depend on what kind of reader you're writing for, too

Comment: @Izkata I think it's called a 'vampie' simply for the fact that it's a reanimated corpse, and therefore a creature in the same vein as the older more classic vampire legends

Comment: @Crettig: Your example would be very out-of-place in a work of fiction, unless the work takes place in a school (or similar) among students learning about Chinese folklore (in which case this might be a passage from one of their textbooks). In particular, it would *not* belong in a work that takes place inside the Chinese folkloric universe.

Comment: @Standback: “If you want the creature to feel familiar to readers, use a familiar English word ... If you don't want this to feel like one of the fantasy creatures readers already know, then use a new name”: This is a completely accurate remark, but one that professional translators have been following for centuries, with a well studied distinction between a source- and a target-oriented approach, not just for transliterations/adaptations of names, but also for word choice in general, syntax of sentences and so on.

Answer (score 19):

The differences between 'fairy', 'elf' 'goblin' and 'demon' are *not* negligible. The fact that a dictionary offers you all of them, or that all have been used in different setting in the past, does not imply that all those words mean the same thing, but that in different situations or contexts, they can be used to describe a Yōsei. (That's the transliteration of the Japanese creature you wish to refer to, right?)

Let me reiterate that: in a certain subset of contexts, 'Yōsei' best translates as 'fairy'. In other contexts, it does not. In a certain subset of contexts, 'fairy' best translates as 'Yōsei'. In other contexts, it does not. Their semantic fields do not wholly overlap.

To find the right translation, you need to have a good understanding of the differences between the various possible terms in the target language - in your case, the difference between 'fairy', 'goblin', 'demon', 'elf', 'spirit', etc. Then, you can pick the word that best fits what you're trying to convey in your story.

Alternatively, you can use a transliteration - 'Yōsei'.

What are some considerations for or against using transliteration rather than an (inexact) translation?

- First, is your Yōsei a major story element, or something mentioned in passing? For something mentioned in passing, it makes less sense to go through the effort of transliterating, and demanding of the reader to learn what a Yōsei is. (You would have to provide the information - sending your readers to Wikipedia is a no-no. But learning is still a mental effort, a small distraction from the story.)
- How different is a Yōsei from whatever word you picked as translation? The greater the difference, the more reason to use transliteration.
- Who is your target audience? If you're writing for children, it's better to stick to familiar words.
- How strongly is your story localised? If your story is very explicitly set in Japan, if there are many other cues that set your story in a specific location, 'Yōsei' fits into the setting, while something as European as 'fairy' does so to a lesser extent.

One thing to remember, if you choose to transliterate rather than translate the term: your English-speaking readers are unlikely to be familiar with Yōsei. You'd have to provide them with the necessary information. This is preferably done by means of the story itself, but if that doesn't work, a footnote is an option. Footnotes are often used in translations, in similar situations, but if you're translating your own story, you can alter it a bit, to incorporate the necessary information into the text.

Comment: 妖精 has roots in Chinese society. The Japanese take it a bit further, and being more westernized than China, recognize the European "fairy" as a 妖精.

Comment: With a loan word which you then have to define.

Answer (score 8):

Does it have to be an actual translation? Translations don't always work, as synonyms get lost in translation. As you mentioned, there is no English word that can mean "fairy", "elf" **and** "goblin".

Translating to any of the options will mean that you lose out some of the ambiguity. Maybe it's important in your story that the creature's alignment is unknown. If you translate it to "fairy", readers will interpret it as good. If you translate it to "goblin", readers are liable to interpret it as conniving or evil. You can't retain the ambiguity.

Instead, you can simply pick a name without any inherent meaning (or suggestion about alignment), and then define the creature through observation rather than naming.

The Wikipedia page you linked has an English variant, where the chosen name seems to be [**Yōsei**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Dsei). Why not use that, so you don't bias your readers and are actually able to assume direct control over steering the viewer's observation; as opposed to relying on existing words with Western connotations?

- **Fairy** = small and benevolent. Has a physical shape but they are inherently magic.
- **Spirit** = ghost or ethereal entity, lacks physical shape.
- **Elf** = humanoid creature with magical affinity and often has an expanded lifespan. Often acts as a counterpart to the human race. Alternatively (but less commonly), very similar to a fairy but not *as* magical in nature.
- **Goblin** = Conniving, tinkerer, likely evil (or at least lacks moral principles). Humanoid, but lesser to elves and humans.
- **Demon** = almost definitively evil. Possible religious connotation (demons are to the Devil what angels are to God; henchmen). Known to possess humans.

These are in no way guaranteed traits, but if the reader reads the word, they are liable to make inferences as to what the creature is like.

Because 妖精 can mean all of these things *at the same time*, the reader is therefore unable to make a choice between the listed interpretations. They must assume a generalized shape. But as English lacks a word that encompasses all definitions, you're much more likely to have your English readers pidgeon hole your creature by the common definition of the word you chose to use.

Comment: Fairies aren't always good. There's a lot of stories that go back to the roots of malevolent or at least uncaring fairies in European tradition. Spelling it "faery" or "faerie" often helps get this across.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Fair point but fairies are more commonly associated with good than evil. Using the different spellings proves my point that _without this hint_ people will usually assume fairies are good.

Comment: I refer you to the idea of "Brownies", which are variously compared to fairies, goblins and gnomes. In most cases they're friendly and helpful unless you take them for granted or are unfriendly towards them, in which case they turn to mischief and mayhem. They're the real folklore version of House-Elves from Harry Potter

Comment: In my experience, fairies are generally outside the very concept of good and evil, and are neither. They might act more good, more evil, or more or less trickstery, but in any case, they are pretty much the archetype of this: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlueAndOrangeMorality

Comment: @neminem: I think you're conflating fairies with _faeries_. They are not the same (the words even come from different etymologycal roots). [Unlike the fairies, faeries are considered to be evil, horrid, and mischievous creatures. When compared to faeries, fairies are friendly and nice. When comparing the two spirits, fairies are very playful and kind. **An example of a fairy is Tinkerbell and an example of a faerie is a banshee.**](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-fairy-and-faerie/)

Comment: @neminem: In short, I think you're assuming fairies and faeries are the same, and therefore they could either be good or bad. But that's not the case, these are separate groups. Fairies generally align as benevolent, faeries generally align as malevolent, or at the very least least indifferent to moral barriers.

Answer (score 3):

To a native American English speaker, *fairy* and *elf* will both connote a positive or helpful mythological creature that may wield magic. *Goblin* will connote a trouble maker, and *demon* will connote a denizen of hell. That may, perhaps, guide your choice.

In wiktionary, 妖精 leans more toward *fairy* than *goblin*. I'd suggest calling them fay-like creatures, or perhaps Japanese fairies. Something like this so the reader knows not to envision typical fairies. White bone demon is an interesting idea and if you decide to do that you will definitely be communicating something non-traditional.

Comment: also: fairies are usually tiny, and goblins are ugly

Comment: Note that sometimes (on some works) elfs are portrayed as shrewd, reserved, detached from short-lived beings, having their own agenda, etc.

Comment: Neither "fairy" (or "faery") nor "elf" is unambiguously positive. There's a strong tradition of stories that use either term to refer to seductive creatures who (for example) entice children away from their families or otherwise cause trouble.  This use is less common now than it was, but is still current. See, e.g., Susanna Clarke, *Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell* for an example of this kind of fairy.

Comment: I'd also consider some of the less well-known in the US European mythological entities, which being less well used, retain more of their original nuanced meanings, having not been Disneyfied: pixie for example... or even the cornish spelling with the connotations of mischief and mayhem: piskie...

Comment: @GerardFalla I love that idea. A few drafts of my own novel referenced something called bixie dust ... I think tweaking an existing thing is a good approach.

Comment: @Jules Discworld even plays on that with its elves. "They are terrific - they beget terror," and then the treatment of elves in the Science of Discworld book involving Shakespeare.

Comment: @GerardFalla -- speaking as somebody who grew up in Cornwall, the name "piskie" just tends to remind me of cheap gift shops, but that could be a very warped perspective...

Comment: @Jules What you said is true, but I think *in general* it's safe to say that "elf" and "fairy" both *connote* a positive (although perhaps a little mischievous) creature, without context. In the vast majority of well-known fairy tales (i.e., not the examples you cited), fairies and elves are "good guys". Only people who read a lot of fantasy would be familiar with (relatively) evil fairies and/or elves.

Comment: @only_pro :-) Indeed, which is why the word 'connote' (to imply or suggest) was used in the answer instead of a word like 'define.' Also, the caveat 'native American English speaker' (not to be confused with a Native American English speaker) was included. But, c'est la vie.

Comment: @only_pro: while I generally agree that most westerners think of fairies as cute, harmless little creatures, I'd like to point out that people who had contact with traditional tales (rather than fantasy), might view fairies as a bit dangerous. I used to read tons of such traditional tales because, even as a kid, I found those potentially dangerous fairies much more exciting than the modern sickly-sweet ones.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be missing one - the Aos Sí (or Sidhe) from Irish mythology. They are the 'fair folk' or the 'lordly ones'. They can be beautiful and hideous. They predict/cause death. They are relatively benign, unless angered. They fit all of fairy, elf and demon.

One Sidhe would give artists and musicians their inspiration - at the cost of their life. Others would steal children.

Modern (IE Tolkien/D&D) elves derive from this as does fairies, banshees, leprechauns and others. Over time these usages have become biased towards cartoonish niceness.

I'ld go for White Bone Demon or White Bone Elf depending on how potentially evil they are.

(would post this as a comment, rather than an answer)

Comment: If an author uses Aos Sí (or Sidhe) in a story, then the story will feel distinctly Irish. In that case, that wouldn't be much different than just using the Chinese pinyin transliteration directly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how much this character is important to the whole story and how much chinese feel you want to retain.

If the character is very important and no english word can express it without distorting its essence, you should invent a new word in english for it. It may be the literal pronunciation of the chinese term or something else. You must give your readers enough details, so that they can picturize it uniquely in their minds.

If the character is not so important, but still cannot be represented by normal english words. You take an already existing word and change its definition in your story. You may define that fairies in your story don't have wings and look ugly. It'll work as long as you maintain consistency.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to maintain a feel of Chinese culture and mythology in your story (which can be very effective but involves a lot more than just translating the story), or you want to adapt the storyline into something that feels more familiar to Western readers.

**If you want to maintain a Chinese feel** then you may want to introduce the entity as "yāojing—a mischievous fairy-like creature without wings" or "a malevolent elf-like creature with powers of enchantment" or whatever is appropriate for the nature of your creature. There is nothing wrong with showing the reader that there is no sufficient word for the creature—in fact, that makes your story more interesting.

**If you want to adapt the story to something more familiar,** and there is just one such creature, give it a name, refer to it by its name, and readers will learn about it as you describe its appearance, history and behaviour. If there are many such creatures, all alike, you certainly can "shoehorn" them into an existing concept like goblin, demon, devil, imp, spirit, shade, ghost, ghoul, spectre, witch, or [familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familiar_spirit). Alternative spellings like daemon, faerie can help emphasise that the creature is a little different to the established concept. Or, you can name your "species" (think of the *Ents* in Lord of the Rings, *dementors* in Harry Potter, or the *Ogier* in Wheel of Time), and describe them as I have suggested above.